# SHOW TRIGGERS privilege without also being able to DROP TRIGGER?

Tags: mysql, permissions, trigger, mysql-8.0

Is it possible to give a user privilege to view Triggers, i.e. execute the `SHOW TRIGGERS` command, without also giving them permission to `DROP TRIGGER`?

Background is, I want to give certain users the ability to make a complete dump/backup/copy of our production database (including triggers), but I want to keep the number of accounts that can actually change the production database as small as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to give a user privilege to view Triggers, i.e. execute
> the SHOW TRIGGERS command, without also giving them permission to DROP
> TRIGGER?

No. In a few words `show triggers` and `drop trigger` requires  the same `trigger` privilege.

- [SHOW
  TRIGGERS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-triggers.html)
  statement returns results only for databases and tables for which you
  have the TRIGGER privilege.
- [DROP TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-trigger.html)  requires the TRIGGER privilege for the table associated with the trigger.

---

[TRIGGER privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger)

Enables trigger operations. You must have this **privilege for a table to create, drop, execute, or display triggers for that table**.

When a trigger is activated (by a user who has privileges to execute INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements for the table associated with the trigger), trigger execution requires that the user who defined the trigger still have the TRIGGER privilege for the table.

Comment: Thats what I feared. Thanks for confirming it. 
Seems like we have to live with the fact that people either can change production triggers or can't view them.

Comment: @BrokenPhysics in fact this should be a feature. Maybe this would exists in the future versions of MySQL